# Bar chart lengths aren't matching values

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm try to create a stacked bar chart of free agency signings in the NHL. So I want the total length of the bar to represent the total dollar amount spent, and each fill chunk represents and individual signing.

I've written the following code below - but two weird things are happening with the scale. #1 - despite being ordered on the sum of each individual cap hit, the bar lengths don't match the values. NYI has the second highest "salary", but their bar is too short. #2, the scale at the bottom is off - FLA spent $23 Million but the scale suggests they spent over $150 Million. I've included the salary values for reference as a geom_text call.

```
nhl %>% 
  group_by(TEAM) %>% 
  mutate(salary = sum(`CAP HIT`)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(Team = fct_reorder(TEAM, `CAP HIT`, sum, .desc = FALSE)) %>%
  mutate(cap = as.character(`CAP HIT`)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Team, salary, fill = cap)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_fivethirtyeight() +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = mycolors) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::dollar) +
  labs(title = "Florida is shelling out the cash", subtitle = "Free agent signings from July 1st to July 4th") +
  geom_text(aes(label = salary))
```

Here is the resulting chart:
[image]

For reference, here is the head of the data frame:

```
PLAYER                    AGE POS   TEAM  DATE     TYPE     LENGTH    VALUE `CAP HIT`
  <chr>                   <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr>    <chr>     <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
1 "Ben Chiarot\xa0"          28 D     MTL   4-Jul-19 Standard      3 10500000   3500000
2 "Cody Ceci\xa0"            25 D     TOR   4-Jul-19 Standard      1  4500000   4500000
3 "Alexander Kerfoot\xa0"    24 C, LW TOR   4-Jul-19 Standard      4 14000000   3500000
```

and you can also find the full csv data here:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hockeyfan22/mackinawstats/master/salaries.csv

Comment: Can you post your complete dataset? It'll make answering your question much easier.

Comment: Cut down your data to a few teams that illustrate the problem, then post an actual reproducible example. In it's current form, this question is quite unlikely to receive a useful answer.

Comment: Thanks I’ll revise when I get back to the computer and will post the full data set.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could further describe your chart. Please specify what each part of the bar represents, what the full bar represents, and on what variable you want to order the bars. My confusion is between your seemingly interchangeable use of "salary" and "cap hit." Perhaps this can be attributed to my ignorance of hockey, but clarification of your first paragraph would be appreciated.

Comment: @PrayagGordy Thanks Prayag - your confusion actually helped me solve my problem as I was also confusing R. Something weird was happening with the scale as a result of the salary = sum(cap hit) - R treated the sum of all the cap hits as the x axis - potentially due to the grouping. Is it best to delete this post now that I have figured it out

Comment: @hockeyfan22 I’m glad I could help! As far as I understand, the goal of Stack Overflow questions is to help others who encounter similar barriers. If you think you can explain why this problem arose, how you recognized your logical flaws, and what steps you took to address them, I think it could be helpful to leave the question on the website. Feel free to answer your question if you can write up a solid explanation. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

use histograms, not bar chart

```
  ggplot(aes(Team, salary, fill = cap)) +
  geom_histogram()
```

you might need to play around with the settings, ie `stat = "identity"`